# select checkbox with hidden input type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir-webdriver

Folks,

I am using watir-webdriver, I have a piece in my HTML DOM which gets generated on the fly when I enter some credentials, this piece has a bunch of checkboxes, the number of checkboxes vary, I have to select one checkbox, below is an example of this, here I want to select the second checkbox(the one that has value "BS" for the input type hidden but the value for input type checkbox is same for all):

```
   <li class="dir">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="$(this).next('.should_destroy').value = (this.checked?0:1)" name="should_not_destroy">
<input class="should_destroy" type="hidden" value="1" name="import[dir_attributes][][should_destroy]">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="import[dir_attributes][][id]">
<input type="hidden" value="Automation" name="import[dir_attributes][][path]">
<span class="dir_mode">Include</span>
Automation
</li>
<li class="dir">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="$(this).next('.should_destroy').value = (this.checked?0:1)" name="should_not_destroy">
<input class="should_destroy" type="hidden" value="1" name="import[dir_attributes][][should_destroy]">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="import[dir_attributes][][id]">
<input type="hidden" value="BS" name="import[dir_attributes][][path]">
<span class="dir_mode">Include</span>
BS
</li>
```

I may be able to do this with XPATH, but wanted to try a non XPATH solution. The input type hidden has the appropriate value that I need, for example above the second checkbox has value "BS" for input type hidden. I tried to use the hidden method like this:

```
h  = @@browser.hidden(:value, "BS")
h.select
```

But I dont know what to do after this. I am trying to select the checkbox based on the value of the hidden element. Any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: So you are trying to get the value out of the hidden field?, or trying to select the checkbox based of the value in the hidden field?

Comment: sorry for not being clear, I am trying to select the checkbox based of the value in the hidden field

Comment: Is it safe to assume this is the markup we have to live with and you can't enact any code-level changes?

Comment: how would a user interact with a hidden control in the first place?  is your intent to test someone (such as an attacker) spoofing input that would normally be impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the visible elements instead. I think it makes it easier to read the test and seems more stable.

Try:

```
@@browser.li(:class => 'dir', :text => /BS/).checkbox.set
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go, I think this will do it

Since you have to select the checkbox based on the hidden, you're going to have to go up a level to the containing li, then drill down to the checkbox

```
@browser.hidden(value: 'BS').parent.checkboxes.first.set
```