# watir webdriver cannot select checkbox input element

Tags: checkbox, webdriver, watir

How would I write this find element statement to run in Watir Webdriver?

```
driver.find_element(:xpath, "//input[contains(@id,'sv')]")

CSS Selector:   #sincro_old > section:nth-child(1) > section:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > nav:nth-child(1) > fieldset:nth-child(3) > section:nth-child(2) > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(23) > input:nth-child(1)
```

Please, any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Attempting to identify the element to be able to check the checkbox.

REF:  "watir webdriver cannot select checkbox input element"

```
<li class="langlist-item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="sv" data-js-id-lang="27" class="form-checkbox form-checkbox--inline">
        <label for="sv" class="langlist-label" title="Svenska">
        <svg class="icon langlist-icon icon--inline icon--xs" role="img">
            <use xlink:href="https://www.bigbuy.eu/public/img/icons/svg-defs.svg#icon-sv"/>
        </svg>
        Svenska    </label>
</li>[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant html to replicate your issue? If this times out: `b.checkbox(:id => 'sv').when_present.set`, it means that it isn't visible on the page. It would be useful to know why.

Comment: Would this be the relevant html to provide:

<input class="form-checkbox form-checkbox--inline" data-js-id-lang="27" id="sv" type="checkbox">

Comment: I have been trying to use CSS Selectors, but none have worked thus far.

Comment: How would I post a screen shot with this CSS Selector code?

< WebElement oCheckBox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='sv']"));
oCheckBox.click(); >

Comment: @LiterateAspects, you should try to put together an example that so that _we_ can see your problem (ie we should be able to copy the page and script locally and see the same error.) Without it, we are guessing in the dark.

Comment: I would love to put together an example, how can I post it?  I have gone through many CSS Selector examples and have all the failed results, and I can post a screen shot of the HTML, but HOW do I post these things here?

Comment: </li><li class="langlist-item">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox form-checkbox--inline" data-js-id-lang="27" id="sv"  
                                            id="sv" />
        <label title="Svenska" class="langlist-label" for="sv">
        <svg role="img" class="icon langlist-icon icon--inline icon--xs">
            <use xlink:href="https://www.bigbuy.eu/public/img/icons/svg-defs.svg#icon-sv"></use>
        </svg>
        Svenska    </label>

Comment: </li><li class="langlist-item">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox form-checkbox--inline" data-js-id-lang="27" id="sv"  
                                            id="sv" />
        <label title="Svenska" class="langlist-label" for="sv">
        <svg role="img" class="icon langlist-icon icon--inline icon--xs">
            <use xlink:href="https://www.bigbuy.eu/public/img/icons/svg-defs.svg#icon-sv"></use>
        </svg>
        Svenska    </label>

Comment: {browser.input(:id, "sv").fire_event('on_click')} is what I have tried but does nothing, from {<input class="form-checkbox form-checkbox--inline" data-js-id-lang="27" id="sv" type="checkbox">}

Comment: @LiterateAspects, you can post those things in your question. Edit it to include the relevant details rather than adding comments (as they are difficult to follow).

Answer (score 1):

The exact equivalent of `driver.find_element(:xpath, "//input[contains(@id,'sv')]")` would be:

```
browser.element(:xpath, "//input[contains(@id,'sv')]")
```

An equivalent, but more Watir-like syntax, would use an `:id` locator with a Regular Expression (for partial text matching):

```
browser.input(id: /sv/)
```

Given that the element is a checkbox and the id does not look dynamic, it would make more sense to do:

```
browser.checkbox(id: 'sv')
```

Comment: Solution found, from a 2012 post by Justin Ko.  If anyone seeking, here the solution for my challenge:

@@browser.li(:class => 'dir', :text => /BS/).checkbox.set

from [I would suggest using the visible elements instead. I think it makes it easier to read the test and seems more stable.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822063/select-checkbox-with-hidden-input-type